# UrlMappings add suffix to controller

Tags: grails

I am trying to add a suffix to the controller that was specified in the url.

I want to map `/admin/mycontroller/` to MyAdminController.

I have tried  a lot of variations with no luck... any suggestions?

```
static mappings = {
    "/admin/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
        controller = controller.endsWith('Admin')?controller: (controller+'Admin')  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I accomplished this by iterating over the controller artefacts and building the url map dynamically:

```
class UrlMappings {
    static mappings = {
        def adminControllers = ACH.grailsApplication.controllerClasses
        .findAll({ it.logicalPropertyName.endsWith('Admin')})
        .collect({ it.logicalPropertyName })

        adminControllers.each { controllerName ->
            def shortName = controllerName - 'Admin'
            "/admin/$shortName/$action?/$id?" (controller: controllerName)
        }
    }
 }
```

Where ACH is a custom `ApplicationContextHolder` as described in this [blog post](http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1017) by [Burt Beckwith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/160313/burt-beckwith).

edit:

this creates the url structure such that `/admin/blah` maps to `BlahAdminController`, but does not include `/admin/blahAdmin`.

Comment: I got something like this to work, please note you dont need the `ACH.grailsApplication.controllerClasses` you can just use `getGrailsApplication().controllerClasses`

Comment: This works but it should be noted that if you do this method, you can not use createlink controller:'nameofcontroller' you have to use params and it caused me great pain.

Comment: Yes, there are quite a few usability issues with reverse URL mappings in grails.

Answer (score -1):

By convention, grails need your controller class name finish with `Controller`

1. I suggest you that you rename your `MyControllerAdmin` to `MyAdminController`
2. I think it may be a problem to name a variable in the url as `controller` if you want to owerride it.
   Try something like :

   ```
   static mappings = {
       "/admin/$cName/$action?/$id?"{
           controller = cName.endsWith('Admin') ? cName : (cName + 'Admin')  
       }
   }
   ```
3. Order matter in `UrlMappings` , check that another rule does not interfere with this one.

Comment: Sorry @Isammoc my controller is named MyAdminController (it was a typo).

Comment: Same way, I guess you want to map `/admin/my/` to `MyAdminController` ?

Comment: I tried what you have above, and could not get it to work.  Have you tried your example(`Cannot invoke method endsWith() on null object`)?

Comment: I didn't try exactly what is above, but I have something similar in my current code (in production now)